# Changing color for Shapefile in Google Earth?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth

I have a shapefile that desrbibes the post/prior routes from/to a certain venue. The white lines are the routes and each segment has a different foot traffic value. The segment in the image has a value of 5923 for example.
[image]

Is there any way to edit this shapefile in Google Earth in such a way that each value will be of a different color?

Like in a gradient, or a certain color would fit a range, for example <6k visits is blue, 6k-10k visits is green and so on.

Comment: Are you working in Google Earth Pro or just Google Earth online ? There are two different programs .

Comment: Working in Pro.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that GE actually is able to load shape-files, up to now I always exported .kml from QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the dialogue when you drag&drop a shapefile into GE?

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept correct answers, in order to ease the problem solution for others having similar questions.